# Why is the generated Code First Migration broken for Update-Database in this instance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I renamed one of my entities from *UploadedFile* to *File* and executed an `Add-Migration`, which resulted in the following;

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.UploadedFiles", newName: "Files");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.UploadedFiles");
        AddColumn("dbo.Files", "FileId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Files", "FileId");
        DropColumn("dbo.Files", "UploadedFileId");
    }
```

After which I executed an `Update-Database` and found that the migration would fail.  I had to re-order two of the statements to make it work;

1. `DropPrimaryKey` needed to be prior to `RenameTable` because the generated code referenced the old table name
2. `DropColumn` needed to be executed prior to `AddColumn` otherwise a multiple identity column error was thrown.

The result was this, which worked as expected;

```
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.UploadedFiles");
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.UploadedFiles", newName: "Files");
        DropColumn("dbo.Files", "UploadedFileId");
        AddColumn("dbo.Files", "FileId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Files", "FileId");
```

**Is it expected that I'll need to hand-edit these generated migrations, or have I done something wrong that is affecting generation?**

Is changing the table name and the primary key too much in one go, and should I instead be executing an `Add-Migration` at each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug, and I'd recommend you [create an issue on codeplex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic). It appears that EF can't determine which statement has higher priority when creating the migration.

Of course, if you used the convention of simply naming the PK `Id` on a table, you'd avoid this issue altogether. I typically find this to be more readable as it prevents PKs from blending in with FKs (eg `Id` and `OwnerId` vs `FileId` and `OwnerId`)